# Universal way to get the current project in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an eclipse plugin which should deal with all opened projects inside Project explorer. It will create an file inside the selected project.

I am using the bellow logic to get the current project.

```
public IProject getCurrentProject() {
    IProject project = null;
    IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        ISelection iselection = window.getSelectionService().getSelection();
        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) iselection;
        if (selection == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
        if (firstElement instanceof IResource) {
            project = ((IResource) firstElement).getProject();
        } else if (firstElement instanceof PackageFragmentRoot) {
            IJavaProject jProject = ((PackageFragmentRoot) firstElement)
                    .getJavaProject();
            project = jProject.getProject();
        } else if (firstElement instanceof IJavaElement) {
            IJavaProject jProject = ((IJavaElement) firstElement)
                    .getJavaProject();
            project = jProject.getProject();
        }
    }
    return project;
}
```

This is working in the developer mode. But after I export as a plugin and install, the following error occurred.

`org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jface.text.TextSelection cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection`

It looks like selection has switched to editor since it has been focused.
Is there any universal way to get the current project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't have a concept of 'current project'. The selection service gives you the selection for the currently active part which may be an editor or a view.

If the selection you get back from `ISelectionService.getSelection` is not an `IStructuredSelection` then the active part is probably an editor. So in that case you can try and get the current project from the active editor using something like:

```
IWorkbenchPage activePage = window.getActivePage();

IEditorPart activeEditor = activePage.getActiveEditor();

if (activeEditor != null) {
   IEditorInput input = activeEditor.getEditorInput();

   IProject project = input.getAdapter(IProject.class);
   if (project == null) {
      IResource resource = input.getAdapter(IResource.class);
      if (resource != null) {
         project = resource.getProject();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! @greg, Always you save me!

Comment: Note that if your code is called as the view changes, upon clicking a tab from a different project, you will receive the old project not the one you just clicked